# MKMapKit true distance between two annotations

Tags: iphone, xcode, mapkit, cllocation, cllocationdistance

I want to make a application that calculates the distance between the user's current location and the nearest something (store, whatnot). Is there any way to obtain the real distance (following public roads ) instead of a direct distance (line from point A to B) ??

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use google API to get the route and distance:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

I don't think you can get the route (following roads) from MKMapKit.

The google maps API will return the route (following roads) as a set of latitude and longitude coordinates. It will also return the calculated distance.